# How would you compute eigenvectors from this linear system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck on a problem and I do not know how to obtain the eigenvectors:

$\frac{dY}{dt}=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-2&0\\ -3&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)Y$

Work: I obtained the eigenvalues $-2,1$ and therefore the origin must be a saddle. However, when I try and obtain the eigenvector, I get the system:

$-4x=0$

$-3x-y=0$.

I am unable to obtain anything from this.

Answer (score 1):

You set up and solve, using RREF:

$$[A - \lambda_i I]v_i = 0$$

The eigenvalues are: $\lambda_1 = -2, \lambda_2 = 1$

The corresponding eigenvectors are:

$$(v_1 | v_2) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $\lambda_1 = -2$, we have the RREF of $[A +2I]v_1 = 0$ as:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 \\
 0  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This means we have $a = b$, so we can choose $a = b = 1$.

For $\lambda_2 = 1$, we have the RREF of $[A -I]v_2 = 0$ as:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 \\
 0  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This means we have $a = 0 $, so we can choose $b = 1$.

Notice how, in both cases, that eigenvector chosen solves the matrix above? Also note that you **cannot** have a zero eigenvector.